# Report Viewer with two tables

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, reportviewer

I create report viewer in asp.net mvc. But I have 2 table has relationship and in the report viewer when i export report the data from other table not coming only the name . 
For example i have in the `Expense` water

but it is not show in table when i do export.

This is my Model :

```
public class Expenses
{
    [Key]
    public int Expenses_Id { get; set; }
    public string Expenses_Type { get; set; }
}


 public class ExpenseDetails
{
    [Key]
    public int ExpenseDetails_Id { get; set; }

    public double Amount { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateExpense { get; set; }

    public int ExpensesId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ExpensesId")]
    public virtual Expenses expenses { get; set; }
}
```

and this is my code for the report :

```
 public ActionResult Reports(string ReportType)
    {
        LocalReport localreport = new LocalReport();
        localreport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("~/Reports/ExpenseReport.rdlc");

        ReportDataSource reportDataSource = new ReportDataSource();
        reportDataSource.Name = "ExpenseDataSet";
        reportDataSource.Value = _context.ExpenseDetails.ToList();
        localreport.DataSources.Add(reportDataSource);

        string reportType = ReportType;
        string mimeType;
        string encoding;
        string fileNameExtension;

        if (reportType == "Excel")
        {
            fileNameExtension = "xlsx";
        }

        if (reportType == "Word")
        {
            fileNameExtension = "docx";
        }

        if (reportType == "PDF")
        {
            fileNameExtension = "pdf";
        }

        else
        {
            fileNameExtension = "jpg";

        }

        string[] streams;
        Warning[] warnings;
        byte[] renderedByte;

        renderedByte = localreport.Render(reportType, "", out mimeType, out encoding, out fileNameExtension, out streams, out warnings);

        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename = expens_report." + fileNameExtension);

        return File(renderedByte, fileNameExtension);
    }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Did you have refreshed the dataset in .rdlc? If was created it before adding a foreign key, you need to drop the .rdlc dataset and datasource, and create a new one.

How about creating a DTO? Sometimes it's easier to create complex list of objects, populate it with the data that you want and send it to rdlc. In this case, you need to have a separate project with the rdlc and add a reference to the main project. That allows you to import DTOs as objects.

```
            List<ExpenseDetailsDTO> list = new List<ExpenseDetailsDTO>()
        {
            new ExpenseDetailsDTO
            {
                Amount = 10,
                DateExpense = DateTime.UtcNow,
                ExpenseDetails_Id  = 1,
                Expenses_Id = 1,
                Expenses_Type = "asd"
            },
            new ExpenseDetailsDTO
            {
                Amount = 10,
                DateExpense = DateTime.UtcNow,
                ExpenseDetails_Id  = 1,
                Expenses_Id = 1,
                Expenses_Type = "asd"
            },
            new ExpenseDetailsDTO
            {
                Amount = 10,
                DateExpense = DateTime.UtcNow,
                ExpenseDetails_Id  = 1,
                Expenses_Id = 1,
                Expenses_Type = "asd"
            },
            new ExpenseDetailsDTO
            {
                Amount = 10,
                DateExpense = DateTime.UtcNow,
                ExpenseDetails_Id  = 1,
                Expenses_Id = 1,
                Expenses_Type = "asd"
            },
        };




        reportDataSource.Name = "testdatasource";
        reportDataSource.Value = list;
        localReport.DataSources.Add(reportDataSource);
```

Something like this has worked for me, at least for the last 4 months while migrating an old API.

Comment: Thank you , so i add this the report  controller?

Comment: No, you need to create a class that contains the fields that you want to display. Then create a list of objects of that class, populate each DTO and then send the list as datasource to the rdlc. Keep in mind that you need to have the rdlc on a separate project and add the reference of your main project so you can add the datasource.